# How to sum across columns automatically?

Tags: formulas, google-sheets

Would like your help to solve the problem as file attached.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E3KTOYHuYIJy9uQKsvlXwbCpwL6cU1IHAQ-Yirb-AfQ/edit#gid=0

I would like each column to sum automatically (using ArrayFormula) when there is new name added and amount added in each row of the same column.

Comment: That is a Google sheet not Excel.  Which of the two are you using?  The formula may be different.  If it is Google sheets then this belongs on WebApps.Stackexchange.com.  If it is Excel then post the data in a mark down text table in the question that shows the data and the expected results.

Comment: Using `Google Sheets` one could use `=ARRAYFORMULA(BYCOL(B7:E13,LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))+B4:E4)` and with `Excel` --> just remove the `ARRAYFORMULA()`

Comment: And what have you tried so far? This is not a free scripting site. We help those who make efforts to help themselves.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: thanks for help. you have help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
=LET(salaries,B4:AA4, raises,B7:AA207 
   BYCOL({salaries; raises}, LAMBDA(c, 
     IF(INDEX(c,1)>0, SUM(c),))))
```

- Range **`B7:AA207`** provides for 200 rows of raises data.
- Range **`B4:AA4`** allows for up to 26 employees.
- You can tweak the range sizes if you think you'll have more (or less) data in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not very familiar with the `Google-Sheets` hence the following formula may be not that very elegant like those who are. However, this is what I have tried and came up with:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B5</kbd>

```
=LET(x, ARRAYFORMULA(B4:4+BYCOL(B7:Z,LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))), CHOOSECOLS(x,SEQUENCE(1,ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(7^89,1/(2:2<>""),1))-1)))
```

---

May be there is more elegant way of resolving this. Using `Excel` I would have done the following as well:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B5</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _LastColumn, COLUMNS(TOROW(2:2,1))-1,
     _LastRow, MATCH(2,1/(A:A<>""))-6,
     _Names, B2:INDEX(2:2,,_LastColumn),
     _Increment, B7:INDEX(7:1000,_LastRow,_LastColumn+1),
     _Salary, B4:INDEX(4:4,,_LastColumn+1),
     _Salary+BYCOL(_Increment,LAMBDA(x, SUM(x))))
```

---

**Note:** There are chances the formula may get slower with increase in data, I have not tested with the same, assuming the reason because i am using lot of empty cells to iterate. Not so elegant solution.

---